# 22.04 screenshots... How to Draw and edit?

Tags: software-recommendation, screenshot, 22.04

I cannot draw arrows and text on top of my screenshots in Ubuntu 22.04 .  I was able to do this in  `flameshot` .

I also tried `Shutter` which is also not enabling me to draw..

How to draw on top of screenshots?

Often to draw arrows, I open a jpg and then screenshot to make quick edits with arrows, etc rather than using gimp or inkscape.

Comment: Why can't you use Flameshot? I use it (on Arch) and it works pretty well. They [have a version for 22.04 (Jammy Jellyfish)](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/flameshot)

Comment: I have used flameshot and have it installed and mentioned it in my post.  I'm not sure what happened with 22.04 but all screenshot programs are messed up now.  Ubuntu 22.04 added an internal screenshot thing.  I guess it broke the other programs.  try in virtualbox and see.

Comment: Gnome 41 broke flameshot: https://flameshot.org/docs/guide/wayland-help/

Comment: it amazes how Gnome broke 3rd party screenshot tools offering a useless app for any person that works with Linux daily. Their argument is that they now care of security ROFL. I ended up installing KDE in Ubuntu.. @Bhikkhu Subhuti , far from a good option, but now Flameshot works...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Gnome Screenshot tool does that and just that, and does it well: take a screenshot. The screenshot is automatically saved to the clipboard *and* in "Pictures/Screenshots", so you can paste the screenshot into any editor, or open the saved file, for editing.

You are also free to use third party screenshot tools like Flameshot. Beware that Ubuntu by default now runs on Wayland. So make sure your utility of choice works well on Wayland. Alternatively, you can still switch to Xorg on Ubuntu.

You can assign the default shortcut keys, <kbd>PntScr</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScn</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScn</kbd> to your own screenshot tool by first disabling the default keybindings. On the "Keyboard" tab in "Settings", select "View and Customize Shortcuts". Disable the default bindings under the "Screenshot" section and create your own bindings under "Custom Shortcuts", assigning the appropriate commands for the tool you prefer to use.

Comment: Confirmed that it is a Wayland issue and works in xorg.  You wouldn't be the Russian / American who worked for Bayer in the 90's?  I knew one who reserved a website called vanadium a long time ago.

Comment: How to get rid of Gnome Screenshot tool? I want to use my Flameshot, and I can't get rid of this built-in garbage. You cannot remove it, you cannot modify save folder... Is it developed by Microsoft? If only way is to downgrade to 20.04 - I will

Comment: I added information on how to assign the shortcuts for printing a screen to your custom tool. Deliberately kept generic, because there are more tools than Flameshot.

Answer (score 7):

Why not use `Draw on your screen` gnome extension to ink over you screen and then take screenshot using the default `Gnome screenshot` tool? `Draw on your screen` extension provides free hand drawing, shapes, pen and other options to annotate the screen.

- Install  `Draw on your screen`

  As of writing this answer `Draw on your screen` extension is not compatible with Ubuntu 22.04. There is a work around though [Install Draw On your screen extension on Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1427416/install-draw-on-your-screen-extension-on-ubuntu-22-04)
- Enable the extension by pressing `ALT` + `SUPER` + `D` and start drawing on your screen.
- Take a screenshot by using `ALT` + `PRTSC` using the default gnome screenshot tool [image]

Comment: For Ubuntu 22.04, I recommend installing `Draw on your screen 2`. It is a fork of `Draw on your screen` made for newer versions of `Gnome Shell`. You can download and follow installation instructions from here: https://github.com/zhrexl/DrawOnYourScreen2