# Install Draw On your screen extension on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, gnome-shell-extension, gnome-tweaks

The `Draw on you screen` gnome extension is currently not supported in Ubuntu 22.04.

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1683/draw-on-you-screen/

[image]

Creating this question to document the steps required for installing the same on 22.04 as a temporary workaround

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Interesting question. Will you be providing an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below steps allows us to manually install the extension on ubuntu 22.04

- Download and copy the extension to your local system

  ```
  # Clone the extension project from git
  git clone https://codeberg.org/som/DrawOnYourScreen.git

  # Rename and move to the project to gnome extension local folder
  mv DrawOnYourScreen draw-on-your-screen@som.codeberg.org
  mv draw-on-your-screen@som.codeberg.org ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
  ```
- Open metadata file for the extension and add gnome version 42 to the `shell-version` array

  ```
  vi ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/draw-on-your- 
  screen@som.codeberg.org/metadata.json
  ```

  The shell version in metadata file should like below after the above steps

  ```
  "shell-version": [
        "3.24",
        "3.26",
        "3.28",
        "3.30",
        "3.32",
        "3.34",
        "3.36",
        "3.38",
        "42"
  ]
  ```
- Open gnome extension manager in chrome https://extensions.gnome.org/local/. The extension should show up in the page. Toggle to enable the extension.
  [image]

Make sure that `gnome-tweaks` and `gnome-shell-extensions` are setup as per https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/install-gnome-extensions-on-ubuntu

- Press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SUPER</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to activate/deactivate extension and start drawing on the screen
  [image]

**KNOWN ISSUES**

After deactivating the extension by toggling <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SUPER</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> and many other short cuts are not working. This is because of the shortcuts in the `Draw on you screen` extension (which are supposed to be active only when the extension is active) are not getting removed after we deactivate the extension. This can be resolved by providing custom key mapping for short cuts in the extension.

- Activate the extension <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SUPER</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>
- Right click to open the menu
- Click Preference icon the bottom row
- Scroll down to view the list of shortcuts
- Double click on the key mapping to assign custom mapping
  [image]

Comment: excellent answer.  The only thing I would add is that you need to log out and log back in (or otherwise restart the gnome-shell) after you edit the metadata.json file.

Answer (score 0):

You can now use `Draw on Your Screen 2` which is a fork of the original and supports all the newer versions. I one click installed it via the `Gnome Extension Manager` in Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.

Link: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4937/draw-on-you-screen-2/

Answer (score 0):

Please notice, that draw-on-your-screen2 will not work on gnome <45 -- thus for ubuntu 22.04 and derivatives, use draw-on-your-screen

After adding gnome version 42 to the metadata.json file as described above, it is probably a good idea to also run:

`sudo cp ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/draw-on-your-screen@som.codeberg.org/schemas/org.gnome.shell.extensions.draw-on-your-screen.gschema.xml /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/`

and then

`sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/`

and then log out/in

Answer (score 0):

I prefer flameshot, because it can be used like lightshot on Windows and it exists in the default packages:

```
    sudo apt install flameshot
```

Head to the system settings and navigate your way to the Keyboard settings. You will find all the keyboard shortcuts listed there, ignore them and scroll down to the bottom.

Now, you will find a + button. Click the “+” button to add a custom shortcut. You need to enter the following in the fields you get:

> ```
>     Name: Anything You Want
>     Command: /usr/bin/flameshot gui
> ```

Finally, set the shortcut to PrtSc – which will warn you that the default screenshot functionality will be disabled – so proceed doing it.

(source: https://itsfoss.com/take-screenshot-linux/)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. (Ubuntu 22.04, kernel 6.5.0-15, gnome 42.9) 
I did all from the 1st comment, but I had to add some from myself:

```
sudo cp ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/draw-on-your-screen@som.codeberg.org/schemas/org.gnome.shell.extensions.draw-on-your-screen.gschema.xml   /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/ && sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
```

Then restart OS and only then enable the extension.

[image: Enabling extension image]

Answer (score 0):

I got fed up trying to make this extension work, and I really NEED this functionality, so I quickly wrote my own program to be able to draw on the screen. It is written in Python, uses Gtk 3 / Cairo, and allows you very basic operations: you can draw lines, write text, move objects around, change colors, save as PNG. It saves state between being called, so there's that. Here it is: https://github.com/january3/screendrawer

Disclaimer: Python is not my mother tongue, and the program is easy enough to understand, so feel free to do with it whatever.